# Pandas Series of lists to one series

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, series

I have a Pandas Series of lists of strings:

```
0                           [slim, waist, man]
1                                [slim, waistline]
2                                     [santa]
```

As you can see, the lists vary by length. I want an efficient way to collapse this into one series

```
0 slim
1 waist
2 man
3 slim
4 waistline
5 santa
```

I know I can break up the lists using

```
series_name.split(' ')
```

But I am having a hard time putting those strings back into one list.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to extract nested lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327856/how-to-extract-nested-lists)

Comment: For those looking to do something similar but keep other columns in tact, similar to a pivot, you may want to check out [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954668/how-to-convert-column-with-list-of-values-into-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here's a simple method using only pandas functions:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([
    ['slim', 'waist', 'man'],
    ['slim', 'waistline'],
    ['santa']])
```

Then

```
s.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

gives the desired output. In some cases you might want to save the original index and add a second level to index the nested elements, e.g.

```
0  0         slim
   1        waist
   2          man
1  0         slim
   1    waistline
2  0        santa
```

If this is what you want, just omit `.reset_index(drop=True)` from the chain.

Comment: Keep in mind that `s.apply(pd.Series)` is creating a DataFrame, whose width is the *longest list in the original series*. So, if you have a series with 10 lists, and one is 500 entries, it will produce a DataFrame with 10 rows, 500 columns, and potentially a lot of NAs!

Comment: Also keep in mind that apply will return a Series if the input is empty, and there is no stack method for Series objects...

Comment: it's so slow in my case.

Answer (score 53):

In pandas version `0.25.0` appeared a new method 'explode' for [series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas.Series.explode) and [dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html). Older versions do not have such method.

It helps to build the result you need.

For example you have such series:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([
    ['slim', 'waist', 'man'],
    ['slim', 'waistline'],
    ['santa']])
```

Then you can use

```
s.explode()
```

To get such result:

```
0         slim
0        waist
0          man
1         slim
1    waistline
2        santa
```

In case of dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  's': pd.Series([
    ['slim', 'waist', 'man'],
    ['slim', 'waistline'],
    ['santa']
   ]),
   'a': 1
})
```

You will have such DataFrame:

```
                    s  a
0  [slim, waist, man]  1
1   [slim, waistline]  1
2             [santa]  1
```

Applying explode on `s` column:

```
df.explode('s')
```

Will give you such result:

```
           s  a
0       slim  1
0      waist  1
0        man  1
1       slim  1
1  waistline  1
2      santa  1
```

**If your series, contain empty lists**

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([
    ['slim', 'waist', 'man'],
    ['slim', 'waistline'],
    ['santa'],
    []
])
```

Then running `explode` will introduce NaN values for empty lists, like this:

```
0         slim
0        waist
0          man
1         slim
1    waistline
2        santa
3          NaN
```

If this is not desired, you can [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html#pandas.Series.dropna) method call:

```
s.explode().dropna()
```

To get this result:

```
0         slim
0        waist
0          man
1         slim
1    waistline
2        santa
```

Dataframes also have [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna) method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  's': pd.Series([
    ['slim', 'waist', 'man'],
    ['slim', 'waistline'],
    ['santa'],
    []
   ]),
   'a': 1
})
```

Running `explode` without dropna:

```
df.explode('s')
```

Will result into:

```
           s  a
0       slim  1
0      waist  1
0        man  1
1       slim  1
1  waistline  1
2      santa  1
3        NaN  1
```

with dropna:

```
df.explode('s').dropna(subset=['s'])
```

Result:

```
           s  a
0       slim  1
0      waist  1
0        man  1
1       slim  1
1  waistline  1
2      santa  1
```

Answer (score 22):

You are basically just trying to flatten a nested list here.

You should just be able to iterate over the elements of the series:

```
slist =[]
for x in series:
    slist.extend(x)
```

or a slicker (but harder to understand) list comprehension:

```
slist = [st for row in s for st in row]
```

Answer (score 19):

```
series_name.sum()
```

does exactly what you need. Do make sure it's a series of lists otherwise your values will be concatenated (if string) or added (if int)

Answer (score 7):

You can try using itertools.chain to simply flatten the lists:

```
In [70]: from itertools import chain
In [71]: import pandas as pnd
In [72]: s = pnd.Series([['slim', 'waist', 'man'], ['slim', 'waistline'], ['santa']])
In [73]: s
Out[73]: 
0    [slim, waist, man]
1     [slim, waistline]
2               [santa]
dtype: object
In [74]: new_s = pnd.Series(list(chain(*s.values)))
In [75]: new_s
Out[75]: 
0         slim
1        waist
2          man
3         slim
4    waistline
5        santa
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `pandas` version is too old to use `series_name.explode()`, this should work too:

```
from itertools import chain

pd.Series(
    chain.from_iterable(
        value
        for i, value
        in series_name.iteritems()
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list concatenation operator like below -

```
lst1 = ['hello','world']
lst2 = ['bye','world']
newlst = lst1 + lst2
print(newlst)
>> ['hello','world','bye','world']
```

Or you can use `list.extend()` function as below -

```
lst1 = ['hello','world']
lst2 = ['bye','world']
lst1.extend(lst2)
print(lst1)
>> ['hello', 'world', 'bye', 'world']
```

Benefits of using `extend` function is that it can work on multiple types, where as `concatenation` operator will only work if both LHS and RHS are lists.

Other examples of `extend` function -

```
lst1.extend(('Bye','Bye'))
>> ['hello', 'world', 'Bye', 'Bye']
```

Answer (score 0):

Flattening and unflattening can be done using this function

```
def flatten(df, col):
    col_flat = pd.DataFrame([[i, x] for i, y in df[col].apply(list).iteritems() for x in y], columns=['I', col])
    col_flat = col_flat.set_index('I')
    df = df.drop(col, 1)
    df = df.merge(col_flat, left_index=True, right_index=True)

    return df
```

Unflattening:

```
def unflatten(flat_df, col):
    flat_df.groupby(level=0).agg({**{c:'first' for c in flat_df.columns}, col: list})
```

After unflattening we get the same dataframe except column order:

```
(df.sort_index(axis=1) == unflatten(flatten(df)).sort_index(axis=1)).all().all()
>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try:

```
combined = []
for i in s.index:
    combined = combined + s.iloc[i]

print(combined)

s = pd.Series(combined)
print(s)
```

output:

```
['slim', 'waist', 'man', 'slim', 'waistline', 'santa']

0         slim
1        waist
2          man
3         slim
4    waistline
5        santa

dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer (by @mcwitt) looks nicely pandas-ish, but is awfully slow, is extremely memory hungry if there are outliers in the size of lists, and buggy (see comments to that answer).

+1 for @Tadej Magajna for his answer, taking the `sum()` over the series. Since it is adding lists together, a more efficient way is using numpy's `flatten()` in case the series elements are nparrays:

**`series_name.values.flatten()`.**