# How to convert column with list of values into rows in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a dataframe like this:

```
    A             B 
0:  some value    [[L1, L2]]
```

I want to change it into:

```
    A             B 
0:  some value    L1
1:  some value    L2
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
In [84]: df
Out[84]:
               A               B
0     some value      [[L1, L2]]
1  another value  [[L3, L4, L5]]

In [85]: (df['B'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]))
   ....:         .stack()
   ....:         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
   ....:         .to_frame('B')
   ....:         .join(df[['A']], how='left')
   ....: )
Out[85]:
    B              A
0  L1     some value
0  L2     some value
1  L3  another value
1  L4  another value
1  L5  another value
```

**UPDATE:** [a more generic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows/40449726#40449726)

Comment: `lambda x: pd.Series(x[0])` should be changed to `lambda x: pd.Series(x)` in case of flat list values in column `B`

Comment: @soupault, that's correct, thank you! This code works for the particular question (that was asked). Partially because of that i have posted a link to a more generic solution...

Comment: @MaxU how can I do that for two columns if they have the same number of values in the list?

Comment: @nurma_a, check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows/40449726#40449726)

Comment: Hi @MaxU--How can we do this in the opposite way? I mean wider format to long format.

Comment: @Roy, for the output dataframe in my answer: `df.groupby("A")["B"].apply(list)` )

Comment: @MaxU. Great. Thanks. If we want only the column value (no index), how can we do that too?

Comment: Oh yeah. Thank you for informing, @MaxU :)

Comment: @Roy, i don't quite understand what do you mean saying "only the column value (no index)". It would be better to raise a new SO question with a small sample input dataset and the desired output

Answer (score 85):

### Pandas >= 0.25

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b'],
               'B':[[['1', '2']],[['3', '4', '5']]]})
print(df1)
```

---

```
    A   B
0   a   [[1, 2]]
1   b   [[3, 4, 5]]
```

---

```
df1 = df1.explode('B')
df1.explode('B')
```

---

```
    A   B
0   a   1
0   a   2
1   b   3
1   b   4
1   b   5
```

I don't know how good this approach is but it works when you have a list of items.

Comment: Perfect! I recalled vaguely that there's a function to perform this in a single step but couldn't quite remember the name and wasn't able to find it again in the documentation. Almost gave in to go with the function chaining solution until I found this :)

Comment: Better than all the other provided solutions

Comment: might want check this issue before using it. (may be wait for 0.26 release) https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/30748

Comment: Rule of thumb: if I can explain in few words, it should take few steps. This answer seems better than the accepted one.

Comment: `df1.explode('B')` does the job. Thanks!

Comment: and you can add `.reset_index(drop=True)` end of the line to remove the same index values. So; `df1.explode('B').reset_index(drop=True)` will be the answer

Answer (score 10):

Faster solution with [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`numpy.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b'],
                   'B':[[['A1', 'A2']],[['A1', 'A2', 'A3']]]})

print (df)
   A               B
0  a      [[A1, A2]]
1  b  [[A1, A2, A3]]


df1 = pd.DataFrame({ "A": np.repeat(df.A.values, 
                                    [len(x) for x in (chain.from_iterable(df.B))]),
                     "B": list(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(df.B)))})

print (df1)
   A   B
0  a  A1
1  a  A2
2  b  A1
3  b  A2
4  b  A3
```

**Timings**:

```
A = np.unique(np.random.randint(0, 1000, 1000))
B = [[list(string.ascii_letters[:random.randint(3, 10)])] for _ in range(len(A))]
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":A, "B":B})
print (df)
       A                                 B
0      0        [[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]]
1      1                       [[a, b, c]]
2      3     [[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]]
3      5                 [[a, b, c, d, e]]
4      6     [[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]]
5      7           [[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]]
6      8              [[a, b, c, d, e, f]]
7     10              [[a, b, c, d, e, f]]
8     11           [[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]]
9     12     [[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]]
10    13        [[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]]
...
...

In [67]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({ "A": np.repeat(df.A.values, [len(x) for x in (chain.from_iterable(df.B))]),"B": list(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(df.B)))})
1000 loops, best of 3: 818 µs per loop

In [68]: %timeit ((df['B'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0])).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('B').join(df[['A']], how='left')))
10 loops, best of 3: 103 ms per loop
```

Comment: This solution is `125` times faster as `apply` solution.

Comment: from itertools import chain

Answer (score 3):

I can't find a elegant way to handle this, but the following codes can work...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([{"a":1,"b":[[1,2]]},{"a":4, "b":[[3,4,5]]}])
z = []
for k,row in df.iterrows():
    for j in list(np.array(row.b).flat):
        z.append({'a':row.a, 'b':j})
result = pd.DataFrame(z)
```

Comment: this was the easiest for me to understand the working.. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the fastest and simplest way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b'],
               'B':[[['A1', 'A2']],[['A1', 'A2', 'A3']]]})


df.set_index('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option

```
unpacked = (pd.melt(df.B.apply(pd.Series).reset_index(),id_vars='index')
 .merge(df, left_on = 'index', right_index = True))
unpacked = (unpacked.loc[unpacked.value.notnull(),:]
.drop(columns=['index','variable','B'])
.rename(columns={'value':'B'})
```

1. Apply pd.series to column B --> splits each list entry to a different row
2. Melt this, so that each entry is a separate row (preserving index)
3. Merge this back on original dataframe
4. Tidy up - drop unnecessary columns and rename the values column