# Pandas: exact string match, with position, between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-matching, n-gram

Let's say I have the two dataframes below.

In reality, both dataframes will be around a million rows each, so I would like to find the most efficient way to compare:

- each df2["BaseCall"] with each df1["seq"]
- return a dataframe that contains a list of positions on each df1["gene"] 
  where any df2["BaseCall"] was found

The overall goal is to count the number of times each feature_id is found in a gene, and capture the position information for use downstream.

```
    # break fasta_df sequences and mutation seqs up into kmers
    data = [{"gene":"pik3ca", "start":"179148724", "stop":"179148949","seq":"TTTGCTTTATCTTTTGTTTTTGCTTTAGCTGAAGTATTTTAAAGTCAGTTACAG"},
    {"gene":"brca1", "start":"179148724", "stop":"179148949","seq":"CAATATCTACCATTTGTTAACTTTGTTCTATTATCATAACTACCAAAATTAACAGA"},
    {"gene":"kras1", "start":"179148724", "stop":"179148949","seq":"AAAACCCAGTAGATTTTCAAATTTTCCCAACTCTTCCACCAATGTCTTTTTACATCT"}] 

    # test dataframe with input seq    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

    data2 = [{"FeatureID":"1_1_15", "BaseCall":"TTTGTT"},
         {"FeatureID":"1_1_15", "BaseCall":"AATATC"},
         {"FeatureID":"1_1_16", "BaseCall":"GTTTTT"},
         {"FeatureID":"1_1_16", "BaseCall":"GTTCTA"},
         ]

    df2= pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

The output should look something like:

```
|  gene  |   feature_id   |   BaseCall   |   Position 
| pik3ca |   1_1_15       |   TTTGTT     |    12
| pik3ca |   1_1_16       |   GTTTTT     |    15
| brca1  |   1_1_16       |   GTTCTA     |    24
| brca1  |   1_1_15       |   AATATC     |    1
| brca1  |   1_1_15       |   TTTGTT     |    12
| brca1  |   1_1_15       |   TTTGTT     |    21
```

This ngram function seems to work great when I use just one test basecall on one seq, but I'm having trouble figuring out the most efficient way to use the apply method with one argument coming from two different dataframes. Or perhaps there is an even better way to find matching strings/positions between two dataframes?

```
 def ngrams(string, target):
    ngrams = zip(*[string[i:] for i in range(6)])
    output = [''.join(ngram)for ngram in ngrams]
    indices = [(i,x) for i, x in enumerate(output) if x == target]
    return indices
```

Comment: Question: I don't see the point of storing the data in dataframe2. Shouldn't that just be a simple dictionary where keys are BaseCall and values FeatureID? Something like `s = pd.Series({item['BaseCall']: item['FeatureID'] for item in data2})`

Comment: (1) How is `Position` computed in your output?  Can you show a specific example?  (2) Is that your complete expected output?  Seems like there are additional matches.  (3) Is is `Basecall` or `BaseCall`, or do you actually have both spellings in your data?

Comment: Df2 is created from many other steps in a long pipeline. I'm not opposed to other data structures if that's more efficient.

Comment: Andrew, position is currently committed l computed using the enumerate function shown on the last line in the ngrams function to return position on the string, which I can then subtract from df1.start.

Comment: And yes, that was not a complete output. I wasn't sure if extra info was helpful, I'll update it.

Comment: It doesn't look like `GTTCTA` appears in `pik3ca`.  Can you confirm, and if so update to correct output?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @andrew_reece. I've updated the results table to reflect reality.

Comment: @SummerEla thanks for updating.  I wasn't clear that the same `BaseCall` could occur multiple times in one string, that's an extra edge case I'll need to account for.  Updating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Account for possible multiple occurrences of same `BaseCall` in a given `seq`, using [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) and [some Pandas hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39955283/2799941):

```
import re

def match_basecall(pattern, string):
    match = re.finditer(pattern, string)
    start_pos = [m.start() for m in match]
    if not start_pos:
        return None
    return start_pos

matches = df2.BaseCall.apply(lambda bc: df1.seq.apply(lambda x: match_basecall(bc, x)))
matches.columns = df1.gene

merged = matches.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

melted = merged.melt(id_vars=["FeatureID", "BaseCall"], 
                     var_name="gene", 
                     value_name="Position").dropna()

melted
  FeatureID BaseCall    gene  Position
0    1_1_15   TTTGTT  pik3ca      [12]
2    1_1_16   GTTTTT  pik3ca      [15]
4    1_1_15   TTTGTT   brca1  [12, 21]
5    1_1_15   AATATC   brca1       [1]
7    1_1_16   GTTCTA   brca1      [24]
```

Multiple `BaseCall` matches are represented as list items in `Position`, but our desired output puts each match on a separate row.  We can use `apply(pd.Series)` to explode a column of lists into multiple columns, and then `stack()` to swing the columns into rows:

```
stacked = (pd.DataFrame(melted.Position.apply(pd.Series).stack())
             .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
             .rename(columns={0:"Position"}))

final = melted.drop("Position", 1).merge(stacked, left_index=True, right_index=True)

final
  FeatureID BaseCall    gene  Position
0    1_1_15   TTTGTT  pik3ca      12.0
2    1_1_16   GTTTTT  pik3ca      15.0
4    1_1_15   TTTGTT   brca1      12.0
4    1_1_15   TTTGTT   brca1      21.0
5    1_1_15   AATATC   brca1       1.0
7    1_1_16   GTTCTA   brca1      24.0
```

We can `groupby` `FeatureID` and `gene` to get occurrence totals:

```
final.groupby(["FeatureID", "gene"]).Position.count()

FeatureID  gene  
1_1_15     brca1     3
           pik3ca    1
1_1_16     brca1     1
           pik3ca    1
```

Notes: Per OP output, combinations with no matches are excluded.
Also, assuming here that `BaseCall` is just one column, and that there are not both `Basecall` and `BaseCall` separate columns.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. Unfortunately, position will be required for downstream coverage analysis which is why I need to track it here.

Comment: Ok, then good to be clear in your post about the requirements for your output.  ("Overall goal" is what I was working with.)  Will add `position` shortly.

Comment: Thank you so much, @andrew_reece, and thanks for being patient with my messy post!