# Filter Dates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Currently have a dataset structured the following way:

```
id_number    start_date    end_date   data1    data2    data3   ...
```

[image]

Basically, I have a whole bunch of id's with a certain date range and then multiple columns of summary data. My problem is that I need yearly totals of the summary data. This means I need to get to a place where I can groupby year on a single occurrence of each document. However, it is not guaranteed that a document exists for a given year, and the date ranges can span multiple years. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am quite stuck.

Sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, '3/10/2002', '4/12/2005'], [1, '4/13/2005', '5/20/2005'], [1, '5/21/2005', '8/10/2009'], [2, '2/20/2012', '2/20/2015'], [3, '10/19/2003', '12/12/2012']])
df.columns = ['id_num', 'start', 'end']
df.start = pd.to_datetime(df['start'], format= "%m/%d/%Y")
df.end = pd.to_datetime(df['end'], format= "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: In the event that a record spans for more than a year, what does this mean for the totals? / How are you wanting to deal with them? (or is that your question?)

Comment: Looking at your data I'm wondering how you would differentiate the data between years. For instance, `id_number` 43482 has a `start_date` of 2/3/2017 and an `end_date` of 3/10/2019 and `data1` of 119. How do you know what the data is for 2018? I would need more info.

Comment: Sure, so if it spans multiple years, that data should stay the same for the years that it spans. So if an id spans from 2005-2007 and then changes in 2008, the data should be the same for the years 2005, 2006, and 2007, and then change in 2008.

Comment: MacItaly, the assumption here is that the data stays the same over the time period of each entry if that makes sense.

Comment: Have considered grabbing each unique id in a list and then working with each id's data points - that is currently where I am at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we have a DataFrame `df`:

```
   id_num      start        end  value
0       1 2002-03-10 2005-04-12      1
1       1 2005-04-13 2005-05-20      2
2       1 2007-05-21 2009-08-10      3
3       2 2012-02-20 2015-02-20      4
4       3 2003-10-19 2012-12-12      5
```

we can create a row for each year for our `start` to `end` ranges with:

```
ys = [np.arange(x[0], x[1]+1) for x in zip(df['start'].dt.year, df['end'].dt.year)]

df = (pd.DataFrame(ys, df.index)
     .stack()
     .astype(int)
     .reset_index(1, True)
     .to_frame('year')
     .join(df, how='left')
     .reset_index())

print(df)
```

Here we're first creating the `ys` variable with the list of years for each `start`-`end` range from our DataFrame, and the `df = ...` is splitting these year lists into separate rows and joining back to the original DataFrame (very similar to what's done in this post: [How to convert column with list of values into rows in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954668/how-to-convert-column-with-list-of-values-into-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)).

Output:

```
    index  year  id_num      start        end  value
0       0  2002       1 2002-03-10 2005-04-12      1
1       0  2003       1 2002-03-10 2005-04-12      1
2       0  2004       1 2002-03-10 2005-04-12      1
3       0  2005       1 2002-03-10 2005-04-12      1
4       1  2005       1 2005-04-13 2005-05-20      2
5       2  2007       1 2007-05-21 2009-08-10      3
6       2  2008       1 2007-05-21 2009-08-10      3
7       2  2009       1 2007-05-21 2009-08-10      3
8       3  2012       2 2012-02-20 2015-02-20      4
9       3  2013       2 2012-02-20 2015-02-20      4
10      3  2014       2 2012-02-20 2015-02-20      4
11      3  2015       2 2012-02-20 2015-02-20      4
12      4  2003       3 2003-10-19 2012-12-12      5
13      4  2004       3 2003-10-19 2012-12-12      5
14      4  2005       3 2003-10-19 2012-12-12      5
15      4  2006       3 2003-10-19 2012-12-12      5
16      4  2007       3 2003-10-19 2012-12-12      5
17      4  2008       3 2003-10-19 2012-12-12      5
18      4  2009       3 2003-10-19 2012-12-12      5
19      4  2010       3 2003-10-19 2012-12-12      5
20      4  2011       3 2003-10-19 2012-12-12      5
21      4  2012       3 2003-10-19 2012-12-12      5
```

**Note:**
I changed the original ranges to test cases where there are some years missing for some `id_num`, e.g. for `id_num=1` we have years `2002-2005`, `2005-2005` and `2007-2009`, so we should not get `2006` for `id_num=1` in the output (and we don't, so it passes the test)

Answer (score 0):

I've taken your example and added some random values so we have something to work with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, '3/10/2002', '4/12/2005'], [1, '4/13/2005', '5/20/2005'], [1, '5/21/2005', '8/10/2009'], [2, '2/20/2012', '2/20/2015'], [3, '10/19/2003', '12/12/2012']])
df.columns = ['id_num', 'start', 'end']
df.start = pd.to_datetime(df['start'], format= "%m/%d/%Y")
df.end = pd.to_datetime(df['end'], format= "%m/%d/%Y")

np.random.seed(0)  # seeding the random values for reproducibility
df['value'] = np.random.random(len(df))
```

So far we have:

```
    id_num  start   end     value
0   1   2002-03-10  2005-04-12  0.548814
1   1   2005-04-13  2005-05-20  0.715189
2   1   2005-05-21  2009-08-10  0.602763
3   2   2012-02-20  2015-02-20  0.544883
4   3   2003-10-19  2012-12-12  0.423655
```

We want values at the end of the year for each given date, whether it is beginning or end. So we will treat all dates the same. We just want date + user + value:

```
tmp = df[['end', 'value']].copy()
tmp = tmp.rename(columns={'end':'start'})
new = pd.concat([df[['start', 'value']], tmp], sort=True)
new['id_num'] = df.id_num.append(df.id_num)  # doubling the id numbers
```

Giving us:

```
    start      value    id_num
0   2002-03-10  0.548814    1
1   2005-04-13  0.715189    1
2   2005-05-21  0.602763    1
3   2012-02-20  0.544883    2
4   2003-10-19  0.423655    3
0   2005-04-12  0.548814    1
1   2005-05-20  0.715189    1
2   2009-08-10  0.602763    1
3   2015-02-20  0.544883    2
4   2012-12-12  0.423655    3
```

Now we can group by ID number and year:

```
new = new.groupby(['id_num', new.start.dt.year]).sum().reset_index(0).sort_index()

    id_num  value
start       
2002    1   0.548814
2003    3   0.423655
2005    1   2.581956
2009    1   0.602763
2012    2   0.544883
2012    3   0.423655
2015    2   0.544883
```

And finally, for each user we expand the range to have every year in between, filling forward missing data:

```
new = new.groupby('id_num').apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.RangeIndex(x.index.min(), x.index.max() + 1)).fillna(method='ffill')).drop(columns='id_num')

             value
id_num      
1   2002    0.548814
    2003    0.548814
    2004    0.548814
    2005    2.581956
    2006    2.581956
    2007    2.581956
    2008    2.581956
    2009    0.602763
2   2012    0.544883
    2013    0.544883
    2014    0.544883
    2015    0.544883
3   2003    0.423655
    2004    0.423655
    2005    0.423655
    2006    0.423655
    2007    0.423655
    2008    0.423655
    2009    0.423655
    2010    0.423655
    2011    0.423655
    2012    0.423655
```

Comment: I believe something is wrong here. I checked this on the DataFrame from my answer, and even though there are no records for `id_num=1` that include `year=2006`, I'm getting `1 2006 5.0` with your code