# how to flatten array in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, series, flatten

Assuming I have a pandas dataframe such as

```
df_p = pd.DataFrame(
   {'name_array':
    [[20130101, 320903902, 239032902],
     [20130101, 3253453, 239032902],
     [65756, 4342452, 32425432523]],
    'name': ['a', 'a', 'c']} )
```

[image: Image of dataframe]

I want to extract the series which contains the flatten arrays in each row whilst **preserving the order**

The expected result is a `pandas.core.series.Series`

[image: Image of expected output]

This question is not a duplicate because my expected output is a pandas Series, and not a dataframe.

Comment: So the `name` column is irrelevant?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds yes, it is irrelevant. Just a sample of the dataframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert column with list of values into rows in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954668/how-to-convert-column-with-list-of-values-into-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Not the accepted answer, but the second one down showing the use of `chain.from_iterable` should work for you---you just need to pass that into the constructor of `Series` instead of `DataFrame`. So: 
`pd.Series(list(chain.from_iterable(df['name_array'])))`

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I've come up with a possible approach (I've posted it as an answer). I don't know whether this is an efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I've figured out. Don't know if there are more efficient ways.

```
df_p = pd.DataFrame(
   {'name_array':
    [[20130101, 320903902, 239032902],
     [20130101, 3253453, 239032902],
     [65756, 4342452, 32425432523]],
    'name': ['a', 'a', 'c']} )

data = pd.DataFrame( {'column':np.concatenate(df_p['name_array'].values)} )['column']
```

output:

```
[0       20130101
 1      320903902
 2      239032902
 3       20130101
 4        3253453
 5      239032902
 6          65756
 7        4342452
 8    32425432523
 Name: column, dtype: int64]
```

Comment: You can remove the `[]` around the data, since you're just putting the new values into a list for no reason. Also, OP asked for a series and you're creating a dataframe and then indexing it with the column name to get a series---you should just be able to use the `Series()` constructor itself without the middle-man :). Edit: lol didn't realize you were OP.

Comment: To be specific I'm saying you could do `pd.Series(np.concatenate(df_p['name_array']))`

Answer (score 5):

The solutions using `melt` are slower than OP's original method, which they shared in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55148969/5087436), especially after the speedup from my comment on that answer.

I created a larger dataframe to test on:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'name_array': np.random.rand(1000, 3).tolist()})
```

And timing the two solutions using `melt` on this dataframe yield:

```py
In [16]: %timeit pd.melt(df.name_array.apply(pd.Series).reset_index(), id_vars=['index'],value_name='name_array').drop('variable', axis=1).sort_values('index')
173 ms ± 5.68 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [17]: %timeit df['name_array'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in x])).melt().drop('variable', axis=1)['value']
175 ms ± 4.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The OP's method with the speedup I suggested in the comments:

```py
In [18]: %timeit pd.Series(np.concatenate(df['name_array']))
18 ms ± 887 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And finally, the fastest solution as provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39959302/5087436) but modified to provide a series instead of dataframe output:

```py
In [14]: from itertools import chain
In [15]: %timeit pd.Series(list(chain.from_iterable(df['name_array'])))
402 µs ± 4.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

This last method is faster than `melt()` by 3 orders of magnitude and faster than `np.concatenate()` by 2 orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.melt`:

```
pd.melt(df_p.name_array.apply(pd.Series).reset_index(), 
        id_vars=['index'],
        value_name='name_array') \
        .drop('variable', axis=1) \
        .sort_values('index')
```

OUTPUT:

```
index   name_array
0       20130101
0       320903902
0       239032902
1       20130101
1       3253453
1       239032902
2       65756
2       4342452
2       32425432523
```

Answer (score 1):

you can flatten list of column's lists, and then create series of that, in this way:

```
pd.Series([element for row in df_p.name_array for element in row])
```