# Is there a pandas function to unpack a column that's a dict into a long format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, long-format-data

So the data has the column **[outbreakMap]** as a **pandas series**. I recreated a snippet of the data as a df below:

Initial Data:
[image]

```
data = {0: {'id': '53545',
  'latitude': -1.5168500000000003,
  'longitude': 105.2985,
  'outbreakMap': {'ob_102795': {'nationalObReference': '403/KPTS/05/22',
    'oieReference': 'ob_102795',
    'outbreakStartDate': '2022-04-12'},
   'ob_102796': {'nationalObReference': '404/KPTS/05/22',
    'oieReference': 'ob_102796',
    'outbreakStartDate': '2022-04-22'}}},
 1: {'id': '53709',
  'latitude': 36.42056,
  'longitude': 139.9085,
  'outbreakMap': {'ob_101531': {'oieReference': 'ob_101531',
    'outbreakStartDate': '2022-04-12'},
   'ob_101644': {'oieReference': 'ob_101644',
    'outbreakStartDate': '2022-04-14'},
   'ob_102290': {'oieReference': 'ob_102290',
    'outbreakStartDate': '2022-04-21'},
   'ob_100121': {'oieReference': 'ob_100121',
    'outbreakStartDate': '2022-03-24'},
   'ob_102949': {'oieReference': 'ob_102949',
    'outbreakStartDate': '2022-05-09'}}}}

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
```

Goal: Unpack the dictionary into a long format like-so:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I went ahead and trimmed a lot of the data to make it more clear and included a screenshot of my dataframe's structure goal.

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT]

I think this is what you want.

```py
def into_long(outbreakMap):
    '''
    Extracting key, oieReference, and outbreakStartDate
    from outbreakMap
    '''
    keys = outbreakMap.keys()
    # return list of tuples
    return [(
        key,
        outbreakMap[key]['oieReference'],
        outbreakMap[key]['outbreakStartDate']
    ) for key in keys]

df['outbreakMap_tuple'] = df['outbreakMap'].apply(lambda x: into_long(x))

# list to multiple rows
# further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954668/how-to-convert-column-with-list-of-values-into-rows-in-pandas-dataframe
df = df.explode('outbreakMap_tuple')

# tuples to multiple columns
# further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550414/how-can-i-split-a-column-of-tuples-in-a-pandas-dataframe
df[['outbreakMap', 'oieReference', 'outbreakStartDate']] = pd.DataFrame(df['outbreakMap_tuple'].tolist(), index=df.index)

df.drop('outbreakMap_tuple', axis=1, inplace=True)

# this is optional
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

The outcome looks like

[image]

I am sure that there are better ways. This is just one of them.

Comment: Hi Jeong, appreciate your help and your additional link to resources, I'll check them out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
lst_3d = [
[
    [data[n]['id'], 
     data[n]['latitude'], 
     data[n]['longitude'], 
     data[n]['outbreakMap'][i]['oieReference'],
     data[n]['outbreakMap'][i]['outbreakStartDate']
] 
    for i in data[n]['outbreakMap']]
for n in data]

#convert to 2d list
lst = [elem for subl in lst_3d for elem in subl]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['id', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'oieReference', 'outbreakStartDate'])
df
Out[1]: 
      id  latitude  longitude oieReference outbreakStartDate
0  53545  -1.51685   105.2985    ob_102795        2022-04-12
1  53545  -1.51685   105.2985    ob_102796        2022-04-22
2  53709  36.42056   139.9085    ob_101531        2022-04-12
3  53709  36.42056   139.9085    ob_101644        2022-04-14
4  53709  36.42056   139.9085    ob_102290        2022-04-21
5  53709  36.42056   139.9085    ob_100121        2022-03-24
6  53709  36.42056   139.9085    ob_102949        2022-05-09
```

Comment: Hi David, I had other comments saying the question was unclear and the data too messy and so I went ahead and cleaned up the provided data and included a screenshot of my df structure goal. Is your response before or after that? Apologies for any troubles.

Comment: @Anonymous check now

Answer (score 1):

While you can build the DataFrame and work on `outbreakMap` column afterwards, it might be easier and more efficient if you modify `data` to include the desired keys to the inner dicts, then construct the DataFrame and `explode` the added columns:

```py
for v in data.values():
    outbreakMap = v.pop('outbreakMap')
    v['outbreak'] = list(outbreakMap)
    v['outbreak_information'] = list(outbreakMap.values())
    
out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').explode(['outbreak','outbreak_information'])
```

Output:

```
      id  latitude  longitude   outbreak                               outbreak_information
0  53545  -1.51685   105.2985  ob_102795  {'nationalObReference': '403/KPTS/05/22', 'oie...
0  53545  -1.51685   105.2985  ob_102796  {'nationalObReference': '404/KPTS/05/22', 'oie...
1  53709  36.42056   139.9085  ob_101531  {'oieReference': 'ob_101531', 'outbreakStartDa...
1  53709  36.42056   139.9085  ob_101644  {'oieReference': 'ob_101644', 'outbreakStartDa...
1  53709  36.42056   139.9085  ob_102290  {'oieReference': 'ob_102290', 'outbreakStartDa...
1  53709  36.42056   139.9085  ob_100121  {'oieReference': 'ob_100121', 'outbreakStartDa...
1  53709  36.42056   139.9085  ob_102949  {'oieReference': 'ob_102949', 'outbreakStartDa...
```

Comment: @Anonymous what do you mean you cannot modify? If you don't want to modify it, you can always use `deepcopy` create a copy and modify on the copy instead.

Comment: Whoops, I misinterpreted your first paragraph and deleted my earlier comment that had a misconception. I do think your solution may be the cleanest and that I can use it to explode the remaining nested column in a wide format which I know how to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since some of the data is duplicated across multiple rows, I think its easier to write a python table and then convert that to a dataframe. Dataframes need to know the full number of rows when they are first created - so pandas would need to make an intermediate list anyway.

Its just a nested for loop that puts rows into a master list, duplicating the data from the outer loop in the inner loop. The data is pulled from the dictionaries via column name lists so we get the right order for each row.

I noticed that outbreakMap appears to be duplicated so skipped it and nationalObReference isn't in all of the data. I also put the code into a function which is an easy way to discard intermediate data that isn't needed after the calculation is done.

```
data = {0: {'id': '53545',
  'latitude': -1.5168500000000003,
  'longitude': 105.2985,
  'outbreakMap': {'ob_102795': {'nationalObReference': '403/KPTS/05/22',
    'oieReference': 'ob_102795',
    'outbreakStartDate': '2022-04-12'},
   'ob_102796': {'nationalObReference': '404/KPTS/05/22',
    'oieReference': 'ob_102796',
    'outbreakStartDate': '2022-04-22'}}},
 1: {'id': '53709',
  'latitude': 36.42056,
  'longitude': 139.9085,
  'outbreakMap': {'ob_101531': {'oieReference': 'ob_101531',
    'outbreakStartDate': '2022-04-12'},
   'ob_101644': {'oieReference': 'ob_101644',
    'outbreakStartDate': '2022-04-14'},
   'ob_102290': {'oieReference': 'ob_102290',
    'outbreakStartDate': '2022-04-21'},
   'ob_100121': {'oieReference': 'ob_100121',
    'outbreakStartDate': '2022-03-24'},
   'ob_102949': {'oieReference': 'ob_102949',
    'outbreakStartDate': '2022-05-09'}}}}

import pandas as pd

def data_to_df(data):
    common_cols = ["id", "latitude", "longitude"]
    outbreak_cols = ["nationalObReference", "oieReference", "outbreakStartDate"]
    table = []
    for index, common in data.items():
        common_row = [common[name] for name in common_cols]
        for ob, ref in common["outbreakMap"].items():
            row = common_row + [ref.get(name, None) for name in outbreak_cols]
            table.append(row)
    df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=common_cols+outbreak_cols)
    return df

df = data_to_df(data)
```

Comment: That's a lot of loops! I'll take a deep dive into your help, thank you.

Comment: The easy way is to sprinkle in some prints and run it.