# Python DataFrame column with list of strings does not flatten

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter, series

I have a column in a `DataFrame` (`production_company`)  which has a list of strings that are production companies for a movie. I want to search for all unique occurrence of a production company across all movies.

In the data below I have given a sample of the column values in `production_company`.

```
"['Universal Studios', 'Amblin Entertainment', 'Legendary Pictures', 'Fuji Television Network', 'Dentsu']"
"['Village Roadshow Pictures', 'Kennedy Miller Productions']"
"['Summit Entertainment', 'Mandeville Films', 'Red Wagon Entertainment', 'NeoReel']"
"['Lucasfilm', 'Truenorth Productions', 'Bad Robot']"
"['Universal Pictures', 'Original Film', 'Media Rights Capital', 'Dentsu', 'One Race Films']"
"['Regency Enterprises', 'Appian Way', 'CatchPlay', 'Anonymous Content', 'New Regency Pictures']"
```

I am trying to first flatten the column using a solution to flatten given in [Pandas Series of lists to one series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885005/pandas-series-of-lists-to-one-series)

But I get error `'TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable'`

```
 17 slist =[]
 18 for company in production_companies:
---> 19     slist.extend(company )
 20 
 21 

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

`production_companies` holds the column `df['production_company']`

Company is a `list` so why is it taking it as `float`? Even list comprehension gives the same error: `flattened_list = [y for x in production_companies for y in x]`

Comment: Hi Sujit, the list comprehension should be `flattened_list = [y for y in x for x in production companies]` although this would just give you individual characters of each string, so I do not know what you would accomplish with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter` to count items. I would split the task into 3 steps:

1. Convert series of strings into a series of lists via `ast.literal_eval`.
2. Use `itertools.chain` to form an iterable of companies and feed to `Counter`.
3. Use a dictionary comprehension to filter for companies with a count of 1.

Here's a demo:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

s = df['companies'].map(literal_eval)
c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(s))
c_filtered = {k for k, v in c.items() if v == 1}
```

Result:

```
print(c_filtered)

['Village Roadshow Pictures', 'Kennedy Miller Productions', 
 ...
 'Truenorth Productions', 'Regency Enterprises']
```

Comment: Thank you jpp. I tried but getting error at s = companies.map(literal_eval) ValueError: malformed node or string: ['Ingenious Film Partners', 'Twentieth Century Fox Film Corporation', 'Dune Entertainment', 'Lightstorm Entertainment'] ... companies = df ['companies']

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce. I took the data you provided for my solution.

Comment: Initial column has | separated values df2['production_companies'].head(20)
Ingenious Film Partners|Twentieth Century Fox ...
Lucasfilm|Twentieth Century Fox Film Corporation
Paramount Pictures|Twentieth Century Fox Film ..
I did a str.split df2['production_companies'].str.split('|').head(20)
[Ingenious Film Partners, Twentieth Century Fo...
[Lucasfilm, Twentieth Century Fox Film Corpora...[Paramount Pictures, Twentieth Century Fox Fil...
[Warner Bros., Hoya Productions]
My requirement to the parse this