# How to combine multiple series into one array or a column of data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I want to standardize the score in each group. After I scaled the data, it returned a series. I cannot create a new column in my data frame and put results in it.

The result I got is like :

- 3M Company                [[1.0], [1.0], [0.9]]
- A.O. Smith Corp           [[1.0], [0.85]]
- AES Corp                  [[1.0], [0.5]]

[result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvi26.png)

The result I want is like:

- [1.0, 1.0, 0.9, 1.0, 0.85, 1.0, 0.5]

In that case, I can put it into new column in data frame. Can anyone help me? Thank you!!

Comment: You should post a small sample of your data frame that others can work off of.  Right now this leaves a lot to interpretation and any solutions might not work for your use case.

Also what have you tried already?  What gave you the result you got currently?

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I tried to upload a picture or table but failed. I will try again.

Comment: It looks like you have a Series where each item is indexed by the name of a company and the value is a list of lists of size 1. Is that correct?

Comment: @brandon Yes. I think that's my situation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a series of lists of lists that you want to flatten. This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885005/pandas-series-of-lists-to-one-series), except that you have one more level of nested lists.

You will have to iterate over each item in the Series and flatten them. Using list comprehension:

```
dd = pandas.Series(
    data=[
        [[1.0], [1.0], [0.9]],
        [[1.0], [0.85]],
        [[1.0], [0.5]]
    ],
    index=['3M Company', 'A.O. Smith Corp', 'AES Corp']
)
flattened = [item[0] for row in dd for item in row]
```

which results in

```
[1.0, 1.0, 0.9, 1.0, 0.85, 1.0, 0.5]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the size of my data is big. I just list part of it in order to illustrate. Also, the result I got is like `array[array[[1.0],[1.0]]]`. I just upload a picture. I think I also need to fix the '[]' outside each number.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sum_array = []
ThreeM = ['1.0', '1.0', '0.9']
AO =  ['1.0', '0.85']
AES =  ['1.0', '0.5']
for x in range(0, ThreeM.__len__()):
    Sum_array.append(ThreeM[x])

for x in range(0, AO.__len__()):
    Sum_array.append(AO[x])

for x in range(0, AES.__len__()):
    Sum_array.append(AES[x])

print(Sum_array)
```