# How to find partial word matches in 2 pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry if this is a similar question, I tried to find one that could answer my specific use-case but I only found ones that give exact matches between dataframes.

I have 2 pandas data frames of descriptions:

df1:

```
Description
i had lunch
going to the airport
buying a suitcase
```

df2:

```
Description
buying lunch
airport travel
owning a car
```

I'd like to filter and/or count how many times `df2` has a matching word that appears in any row of `df1`

so for example `df2` has the words 'lunch' and 'airport' and those single words appear in `df1`, so I would like to pull out and count the rows in `df2` that have that match.

So my output is just a filtered `df2` based on single word matches in `df1`.

Example output filtered would be:

df2:

```
Description
buying lunch
airport travel
```

Is there a way I can do this with pandas dataframes?

Example input data:

```
d = {'Description': ['i had lunch', 'going to the airport', 'buying a suitcase']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d = {'Description': ['buying lunch', 'airport travel', 'owning a car']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: How to deal with definite article `a` in 3rd row?

Comment: Should the match be per row or globally?

Comment: sorry I am not experience so let me know if this answer is not quite right. I believe I am looking for a global match - the words in df2 can appear anywhere in df1 and I want to filter to those rows. So I mean that I am not looking for row 1 to match just row 1 between dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### globally

To match globally (any row of df1 with any row of df2), you can use:

```
import re
regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, df1['Description'].str.split().explode().unique()))

out = df2[df2['Description'].str.contains(fr'\b({regex})\b')]
```

To count:

```
df2['Description'].str.contains(fr'\b({regex})\b').sum()
```

Output: `3`

##### per row

If you want to match each pair of row:

```
matches = [bool(set(a.split())&set(b.split()))
           for a,b in zip(df1['Description'].str.lower(),
                          df2['Description'].str.lower())]
```

output: `[True, True, True]`

To count:

```
count = sum(bool(set(a.split())&set(b.split()))
            for a,b in zip(df1['Description'].str.lower(),
                          df2['Description'].str.lower())
            )
```

Output: `3`

##### excluding small words

```
blacklist = {'a'}

matches = [bool(set(a.split())&set(b.split())-blacklist)
           for a,b in zip(df1['Description'].str.lower(),
                          df2['Description'].str.lower())]
```

output: `[True, True, False]`

Answer (score 0):

so i think you should look into the [pandas split method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html).

i'm not too sure how exactly to implement this but in reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885005/pandas-series-of-lists-to-one-series) something along the lines of this might work:

```
result = df2.loc[df2['Description'].isin(df1['Description'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(drop=True).tolist())
```

basically you split the strings of df1 into single words and convert them into a list. then you can check where a string of df2 contains any word of df1 with the .isin() method.

hope this helps :)