# Iterating over a list that has a combination of nested lists of different sizes, with itertools

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

Lets say that I have the following list.

```
strange_list = [3, 4, 5, [6, 7, 8, [9, 0, 9], 4, 34, 'hello'], [[[['wtf']]]]]
```

How do I get the following list, using some function in itertools module.

```
chain_strange_list = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 9, 4, 34, 'hello', 'wtf']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to extract nested lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327856/how-to-extract-nested-lists)

Comment: See [collapse](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#combining) in more_itertools.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Comment: I use `flatten = lambda *n: (e for a in n
 for e in (flatten(*a) if isinstance(a, (tuple, list)) else (a,)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make a simple recursive function to deal with this without needing any imports.

```
def unpack(obj):
    if not isinstance(obj, list):
        yield obj
    else:
        for item in obj:
            yield from unpack(item)

list(unpack(strange_list))
>> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 9, 4, 34, 'hello', 'wtf']
```

Keep in mind the base condition here is simple in that it checks if the current item in the iteration is a list. For more complex data types you would have to modify this condition to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is flattening of a list, you can check those:
[how to extract nested lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327856/how-to-extract-nested-lists)
[Flatten list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264684/flatten-list-of-lists)
[How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

so following one of them and thanks to @Chris Charley for a tip:

```py
from more_itertools import collapse
strange_list = [3, 4, 5, [6, 7, 8, [9, 0, 9], 4, 34, 'hello'], [[[['wtf']]]]]

list(collapse(strange_list))
# [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 9, 4, 34, 'hello', 'wtf']
```