# Un-nesting nested lists

Tags: python

Hi I was wondering how I could un-nest a nested nested list. I have:

```
list = [[[1,2,3]], [[4,5,6]], [[7,8,9]]]
```

I would like to to look as follows:

```
new_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

How to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> L = [[[1,2,3]], [[4,5,6]], [[7,8,9]]]
>>> [x[0] for x in L]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

For multiple nestings:

```
def unnesting(l):
    _l = []
    for e in l:
        while isinstance(e[0], list):
            e = e[0]
        _l.append(e)
    return _l
```

A test:

```
In [24]: l = [[[1,2,3]], [[[[4,5,6]]]], [[[7,8,9]]]]
In [25]: unnesting(l)
Out[25]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that might be easier and quicker [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860476/how-to-unnest-a-nested-list) and also mentioned [here](https://code-paper.com/python/examples-unlist-list-python#:%7E:text=python%20how%20to%20unnest%20a%20nested%20list%20%23,from%20the%20itertools%20package%20and%20is%20useful%20for).

```
from itertools import chain

nested_list = [[[1,2,3]], [[4,5,6]], [[7,8,9]]]
my_unnested_list = list(chain(*nested_list))
print(my_unnested_list)
```

which results in your desired output as:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```