# Mean of elements over a list

Tags: r

I want to get the mean over all elements of this list. I want the result to be a single number. I have tried sapply but does not provide desired result.

```r
[[1]]
[1] 6.3

[[2]]
[1] 5.8

[[3]]
[1] 7.1

[[4]]
[1] 6.3

[[5]]
[1] 6.5

[[6]]
[1] 7.6

[[7]]
[1] 4.9

[[8]]
[1] 7.3

[[9]]
[1] 6.7

[[10]]
[1] 7.2

[[11]]
[1] 6.5

[[12]]
[1] 6.4

[[13]]
[1] 6.8

[[14]]
[1] 5.7

[[15]]
[1] 5.8

[[16]]
[1] 6.4

[[17]]
[1] 6.5

[[18]]
[1] 7.7

[[19]]
[1] 7.7

[[20]]
[1] 6

[[21]]
[1] 6.9

[[22]]
[1] 5.6

[[23]]
[1] 7.7

[[24]]
[1] 6.3

[[25]]
[1] 6.7

[[26]]
[1] 7.2

[[27]]
[1] 6.2

[[28]]
[1] 6.1

[[29]]
[1] 6.4

[[30]]
[1] 7.2

[[31]]
[1] 7.4

[[32]]
[1] 7.9

[[33]]
[1] 6.4

[[34]]
[1] 6.3

[[35]]
[1] 6.1

[[36]]
[1] 7.7

[[37]]
[1] 6.3

[[38]]
[1] 6.4

[[39]]
[1] 6

[[40]]
[1] 6.9

[[41]]
[1] 6.7

[[42]]
[1] 6.9

[[43]]
[1] 5.8

[[44]]
[1] 6.8

[[45]]
[1] 6.7

[[46]]
[1] 6.7

[[47]]
[1] 6.3

[[48]]
[1] 6.5

[[49]]
[1] 6.2

[[50]]
[1] 5.9
```

Answer (score 1):

The list you have seems to be fifty numerical vectors, each of length 1. If you just want the mean of all elements in the list use the `unlist()` function

```
mean(unlist(...))
```

Put the name of the list object where `...` is. The `unlist()` function will break it into a single vector, in this case with a length of fifty. The `mean()` function simply takes the mean of a vector, that's why you need to convert your list to a vector.

```
# example data
listA <- list(4,6,9,6,4,5,2,4,9,8,6,3,5,2,7)
# mean of the list
mean(unlist(listA))
```

Comment: Is there `unlist` method in Python? What is it doing?

Comment: Looks like it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860476/how-to-unnest-a-nested-list