# getting all elements of a python list ,including sublists

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

I have a python list whose elements can be letters or lists of letters.I wanted to write a function to extract all elements as below

suppose

```
l=['a',['b',['c']] ]

The output need to be ['a','b','c']
```

I thought recursion would be the correct way to do this.
The base case may be that the list contains only one element.
I tried to code this..but the output is

```
['a', 'b', ['c']]
```

Can someone please tell me what went wrong here?

```
def get_all_elements(mylist):
    if len(mylist)==1:
        return mylist[0]
    else:
        output=[mylist[0]]
        output+=get_all_elements(mylist[1:])
        return output
```

Comment: Are they always single letters?

Comment: are the lists nested arbitrarily deep, or 3 deep at max?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work Ok:

```
def flatten(iterable):
   out = []
   for i in iterable:
      if hasattr(i,'__iter__'):
         out.extend(flatten(i))
      else:
         out.append(i)
   return out

l=['a',['b',['c']] ]   
print flatten(l)
```

Where you went wrong is that in your solution, `mylist[0]` can itself be a list (of length 1) which contains another list (of arbitrary length).  In that case, you just returned it.

Answer (score 1):

When you check to see if `mylist` is of length 1, you don't check for the case where its contents are a list. Here's an example that will highlight your problem.

```
get_all_elements([1, [2, [3, 4]]])
```

If you want a complete solution, [Flattening a shallow list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python) and [Comprehension for flattening a sequence of sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457215/comprehension-for-flattening-a-sequence-of-sequences) are good places to look.

Answer (score 0):

this will work on up to 3 levels deep, if the depth is arbitrary i don't think you'll be able to use a list comprehension.

```
[grandchild for parent in l for child in parent for grandchild in child]
```