# How to get largest value from the 2-d array in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

suppose I have the values in 2-d array as:

```
array = [[0.12],[0.24],[1.24],[1.45],[2.05],[0.45]]
```

and I have to find the largest value from above, so the result should be only: `2.05`
please give me the idea for this. (without iterations if there is precise code then better)

Comment: Did you have any ideas in mind yourself? If you tried something and it didnt work, thats ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way without having to `import` any modules:

```
>>> array = [[0.12],[0.24],[1.24],[1.45],[2.05],[0.45]]
>>> max([item for sublist in array for item in sublist])
2.05
```

List comprehensions to the rescue!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is:

```
from itertools import chain

array = [[0.12],[0.24],[1.24],[1.45],[2.05],[0.45]]
value = max(chain.from_iterable(array))
#2.05
```

A key term you may have been missing to find related posts to this is "flattening" - some useful posts:

#### How to flatten lists

1. [Flattening a shallow list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)
2. [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)
3. [Comprehension for flattening a sequence of sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457215/comprehension-for-flattening-a-sequence-of-sequences)

Comment: Not that it is any better, but maybe worth noting you can use `chain` with unpacking of the iterable: `max(chain(*array))`