# python pandas flatten a dataframe to a list

Tags: python, list, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like so:

```
import pandas
a=[['1/2/2014', 'a', '6', 'z1'], 
   ['1/2/2014', 'a', '3', 'z1'], 
   ['1/3/2014', 'c', '1', 'x3'],
   ]
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(a[1:],columns=a[0])
```

I want to flatten the df so it is one continuous list like so:

`['1/2/2014', 'a', '6', 'z1', '1/2/2014', 'a', '3', 'z1','1/3/2014', 'c', '1', 'x3']`

I can loop through the rows and `extend` to a list, but is a much easier way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comprehension for flattening a sequence of sequences?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457215/comprehension-for-flattening-a-sequence-of-sequences)

Comment: i looked at that above answer when searching for an answer. That question isn't a dataframe setting. If that answer solved my problem, I wouldn't have needed to post my question.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can use [`.flatten()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) on the DataFrame converted to a NumPy array:

```
df.to_numpy().flatten()
```

and you can also add [`.tolist()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) if you want the result to be a Python `list`.

### Edit

In previous versions of Pandas, the `values` attributed was used instead of the `.to_numpy()` method, as mentioned in the comments below.

Comment: pandas now [recommends](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) using `.to_numpy()` instead of `.values`.

Comment: @Frank Why?  `.values` already exists, it's a numpy array under the hood. Why call a function?

Comment: @endolith I'm just passing along what the docs say – ask them, not me. Some more context here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508052

Answer (score 20):

Maybe use [stack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)?

```
df.stack().values
array(['1/2/2014', 'a', '3', 'z1', '1/3/2014', 'c', '1', 'x3'], dtype=object)
```

(**Edit:** Incidentally, the DF in the Q uses the first row as labels, which is why they're not in the output here.)

Answer (score 4):

You can try with numpy

```
import numpy as np
np.reshape(df.values, (1,df.shape[0]*df.shape[1]))
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)  method

```py
df.values.reshape(-1)
```

Comment: Hi ahmed, you could improve your answer formatting your code, putting links to the official documentation and finally writing the output gotten using your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The previously mentioned `df.values.flatten().tolist()` and `df.to_numpy().flatten().tolist()` are concise and effective, but I spent a very long time trying to learn how to 'do the work myself' via list comprehension and without resorting built-in functions.

For anyone else who is interested, try:

**`[  row for col in df for row in df[col]  ]`**

Turns out that this solution to flattening a `df` via list comprehension (which I haven't found elsewhere on SO) is just a small modification to the solution for flattening nested lists (that can be found all over SO):

`[ val for sublst in lst for val in sublst ]`