# pandas series containing arrays

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column which looks a little like:

```
Out[67]:
0      ["cheese", "milk...
1      ["yogurt", "cheese...
2      ["cheese", "cream"...
3      ["milk", "cheese"...
```

now, ultimately I would like this as a flat list, but in attempting to flatten this, i noticed that pandas treats `["cheese", "milk", "cream"]` as `str` rather than `list`

How would i go about flattening this so I end up with:

```
["cheese", "milk", "yogurt", "cheese", "cheese"...]
```

[EDIT]
So the answer given below appears to be:

`s = pd.Series(["['cheese', 'milk']", "['yogurt', 'cheese']", "['cheese', 'cream']"])`

```
s = s.str.strip("[]")
df = s.str.split(',', expand=True)
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace("'", '').strip())
l = df.values.flatten()
print (l.tolist())
```

Which is great, question answered, answer accepted but it strikes me as rather inelegant solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pandas flatten a dataframe to a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440008/python-pandas-flatten-a-dataframe-to-a-list)

Comment: No, it is not duplicate, because `type` of column is `string` not `list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) and then flat nested `lists` - [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python):

```
print df
                  a
0    [cheese, milk]
1  [yogurt, cheese]
2   [cheese, cream]

print df.a.values
[[['cheese', 'milk']]
 [['yogurt', 'cheese']]
 [['cheese', 'cream']]]

l = df.a.values.flatten()
print l
[['cheese', 'milk'] ['yogurt', 'cheese'] ['cheese', 'cream']]

print [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
['cheese', 'milk', 'yogurt', 'cheese', 'cheese', 'cream']
```

EDIT:

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(["['cheese', 'milk']", "['yogurt', 'cheese']", "['cheese', 'cream']"])

#remove []
s = s.str.strip('[]')
print s
0      'cheese', 'milk'
1    'yogurt', 'cheese'
2     'cheese', 'cream'
dtype: object

df = s.str.split(',', expand=True)
#remove ' and strip empty string
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace("'", '').strip())
print df
        0       1
0  cheese    milk
1  yogurt  cheese
2  cheese   cream

l = df.values.flatten()
print l.tolist()
['cheese', 'milk', 'yogurt', 'cheese', 'cheese', 'cream']
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in `df.values.a.flatten()` it should instead be `df.a.values.flatten()`

Comment: this just prints each individual letter for me:

`s = pd.Series(["['cheese', 'milk']", "['yogurt', 'cheese']", "['cheese', 'cream']"])`
`l = s.values.flatten()`
`print ([item for sublist in l for item in sublist])`

Comment: Well, i can't deny that it works so thanks for that. I'm a little surprised though that the answer is so unwieldily

Answer (score 0):

To convert the column values from str to list you could use `df.columnName.tolist()` and for flattening you could do `df.columnName.values.flatten()`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `Series` into a `DataFrame` and then call `stack`:

```
s.apply(pd.Series).stack().tolist()
```

Comment: this returns a list of strings containing ['milk', 'cheese'] `s = pd.Series(["['cheese', 'milk']", "['yogurt', 'cheese']", "['cheese', 'cream']"])`

`s.apply(pd.Series).stack().tolist()`

Comment: From the original description, I thought it was the type of the `Series` was a list of strings: `s2 = pd.Series([['cheese', 'milk'], ['yogurt', 'cheese'], ['cheese', 'cream']])`, in which case `s2.apply(pd.Series).stack().tolist()` should work.  If the type of the `Series` is a string representing a list of strings, you could add an eval: `s.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(eval(x))).stack().tolist()`