# pandas.DataFrame: how to applymap() with external arguments

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

SEE UPDATE AT THE END FOR A MUCH CLEARER DESCRIPTION.

According to http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html you can pass external arguments to an apply function, but the same is not true of applymap: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap

I want to apply an elementwise function `f(a, i)`, where `a` is the element, and `i` is a manually entered argument. The reason I need that is because I will do `df.applymap(f)` in a loop `for i in some_list`.

To give an example of what I want, say I have a DataFrame `df`, where each element is a `numpy.ndarray`. I want to extract the `i`-th element of each `ndarray` and form a new DataFrame from them. So I define my `f`:

```
def f(a, i):
    return a[i]
```

So that I could make a loop which would return the i-th element of each of the `np.ndarray` contained in `df`:

```
for i in some_series:
    b[i] = df.applymap(f, i=i)
```

so that in each iteration, it would pass my value of `i` into the function `f`.

I realise it would all have been easier if I had used MultiIndexing for `df` but for now, this is what I'm working with. Is there a way to do what I want within pandas? I would ideally like to avoid for-looping through all the columns in `df`, and I don't see why `applymap` doesn't take keyword arguments, while `apply` does.

Also, the way I currently understand it (I may be wrong), when I use `df.apply` it would give me the `i`-th element of each row/column, instead of the `i`-th element of each `ndarray` contained in `df`.

---

UPDATE:

So I just realised I could split `df` into Series and then use the `pd.Series.apply` which could do what I want. Let me just generate some data to show what I mean:

```
def f(a,i):
    return a[i]

b = pd.Series(index=range(10), dtype=object)
for i in b.index:
    b[i] = np.random.rand(5)

b.apply(f,args=(1,))
```

Does exactly what I expect, and want it to do. However, trying with a DataFrame:

```
b = pd.DataFrame(index=range(4), columns=range(4), dtype=object)
for i in b.index:
    for col in b.columns:
        b.loc[i,col] = np.random.rand(10)

b.apply(f,args=(1,))
```

Gives me `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 10), indices imply (4, 4)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it:

```
def matchValue(value, dictionary):
    return dictionary[value]

a = {'first':  1, 'second':  2}
b = {'first': 10, 'second': 20}
df['column'] = df['column'].map(lambda x: matchValue(x, a))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution where argument is stored within a nested method

```
f(cell,argument):
    """Do something with cell value and argument"""
    return output

def outer(argument):
   def inner(cell):
        return f(cell,argument)

   return inner 

argument = ...
df.applymap(func = outer(argument))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) doesn't accept arguments, `DataFrame.applymap(func)`. If you want to maintain an `i` as state, you can store it as a global variable that's accessed/modified by `func`, or use a `decorator`.

However, I would recommend you to try the [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method.

Comment: See the update. Is there a way to make the apply function do what I want? I don't really understand the error it's giving me (there's a ton of text), but I assumed it's trying to return the `i`-th row of `b`, instead of the `i`-element of each element of b.

Comment: Do you want to use `f` on a list or series, or on a 2D dataframe? Pandas `apply` applies function along input axis of DataFrame. And `applymap` apply a function to a DataFrame that is intended to operate elementwise, i.e. like doing map(func, series) for each series in the DataFrame.

Comment: Essentially I would like the functionality of applymap (so apply `func` on each element of `df`/`b`), while being able to pass my "external" argument `i` into `func`. As you said, it seems I could use global variables or perhaps function attributes or something, or just split `df` into Series, but I was just wondering if there was a way to do that directly within pandas.

Comment: It depends on how do you define your `i-th` element of a 2D array? If it is `i = row * n_col + col`, pandas doesn't have a direct way for that, but you may consider using `apply` twice or [flattening the dataframe to a list first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440008/python-pandas-flatten-a-dataframe-to-a-list).