# Change Shape of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that will always start out being 5 across, but it could be any height.  Ie:

```
 1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
    ...
41 42 43 44 45
```

I want to rearrange the dataframe to look like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... 45
```

What's the best way of doing this?  I assume there is a good one-liner that I am missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas flatten a dataframe to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440008/python-pandas-flatten-a-dataframe-to-a-list)

Comment: `df.values.ravel()`?

Comment: It seems like it flattens to one column, rather than (in the example) 45 columns in one row.  Do you have any suggestions to do this best? Transpose seems to not do it.

Comment: Although I do not understand fully why, df = np.empty([1,45]) does change the shape of df correctly..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
df.stack().values
```