# How to mix two pandas columns into one dataframe with first element from first column, second element from second column and so on?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Imagine I have pandas dataframe:

**Column1** **Column2**

```
A            D

B            E

C            F
```

How to get resulting Dataframe in this form?

**Column**

```
 A
 D
 B
 E
 C
 F
```

Comment: Are there empty rows in your starting dataframe?

Comment: no, it is all filled.

Comment: `df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: have you tried df.values.flatten() and then reshaping it? it returns a numpy array but you can turn that back into a dataframe if you want. Relevant answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440008/python-pandas-flatten-a-dataframe-to-a-list

Comment: Perfect @MichaelSzczesny, it is working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: see the benchmark below for a slightly faster solution.

You can do this:

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd

# The data
data = [["A", "D"], ["B", "E"], ["C", "F"]]

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Column1", "Column2"]) 

# Flatten and convert to DataFrame
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().flatten())

print(df)
```

Output:

```
A
D
B
E
C
F
```

`new_df` will be a `pandas.DataFrame`.

Note the use of [`df.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) too.

And as suggested by @Michael Szczesny you can do:

```
new_series = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which wil return a `pandas.Series`.

**Addded Benchmark:**

Based on @Mayank Porwal's answer I add this benchmark results.
I used timeit.repeat with `repeat = 7, number = 10000`.
Sorted from fastest to slowest:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().ravel('A')) # 51.0 µs
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().ravel('K')) # 51.0 µs
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().ravel('F')) # 51.1 µs
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().flatten())  # 52.6 µs
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().ravel('C')) # 53.4 µs
new_series = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)  # 322.0 µs
```

Using `numpy.ravel` is fastest mainly because it returns a view whereas `numpy..to_numpy()` returns a copy.
For details about `numpy.ravel` see: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html

In short, "A" will force to read the elements in Fortran-like index order if the array is Fortran contiguous in memory and with "K" it will read the elements in the order they occur in memory.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`df.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) with [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
In [2349]: x = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().ravel('F'))

In [2350]: x
Out[2350]: 
     0
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
5    F
dtype: object
```

**Note: This will be quite performant.**

**Timing comparisons:**

```
In [2369]: dd = pd.concat([df] * 1000)

# Rivers' answers:

In [2369]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(dd.to_numpy().flatten())
95.6 µs ± 1.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [2371]: %timeit dd.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
919 µs ± 9.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# My answer:

In [2372]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(dd.to_numpy().ravel('F'))
62 µs ± 577 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: @Augustas please check my answer. It has the best performance.

Comment: I didn't thought speed performance could be important for this task, good idea, thanks, I'll edit my answer.