# Pandas - convert data into list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file.xlsx with numbers in one column. I want it to convert into a list in python. The problem is when I run the code, the output is:

```
[[123], [234], [345], ...]
```

but want it to be

```
["123", "234", "345", ...]
```

How can I "delete" the additional " [] "?

```
import pandas as pd


excel_file = pd.read_excel(r'C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\file.xlsx')
excel_list = excel_file.values.tolist()

print(excel_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unwrap the 1-item lists with a list comprehension that accesses the zeroth member of the list:

```
excel_list = [[123], [234], [345]]  # stand-in for your current reading code

excel_list = [item[0] for item in excel_list]  # unwrap the lists
```

However, it's better to just tell Pandas that the first line is a header (if it is):

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = pd.read_excel(r'so71568988.xlsx', header=1)
print(excel_file)
excel_list = excel_file["values"].tolist()
print(excel_list)
```

outputs

```
   values
0     123
1     456
2     790
3   35932
[123, 456, 790, 35932]
```

without extra unwrapping.

Answer (score 1):

You can also flatten the array before converting to list.

```
import pandas as pd


excel_file = pd.read_excel(r'C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\file.xlsx')
excel_list = excel_file.values.flatten().tolist()

print(excel_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.flatten()` on the DataFrame converted to a NumPy array:

```
df.to_numpy().flatten()
```

Please refer to the **original thread** here - [python pandas flatten a dataframe to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440008/python-pandas-flatten-a-dataframe-to-a-list)

**Docs link** - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html